# How to find what the "Mate version" of programs are called

Tags: command-line, gui, mate-desktop

On Mate systems, many programs correspond to (and are sometimes forks of) other programs with more well-known names:

- `nautilus` -> `caja`
- `gnome-terminal` -> `mate-terminal`
- `ark` -> `engrampa`
- `gedit` -> `pluma`

Sometimes I get lucky and just replace `gnome` with `mate`.  Sometimes I have to resort to opening a file through a GUI and play games with `xprop` or rely on the help menu to find which command was actually called.  Other times I get lucky on Google and get [some random list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Utilities#Graphical).

Is there some command line trick I don't know about to get the name of these Mate programs?

Comment: There is another random list at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222343/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Most Linux distributions provide some set of basic utility programs - graphical text editor, image viewer, file manager, window manager, terminal emulator, and so on. While some of these programs' names could be possible to get rather easily, if you are checking this on somebody's system and not a fresh install, you can never be sure, since they might have changed default applications.

Well, nevertheless, you might check default applications:

`cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

I guess that Mate should have something like this too. You could then `grep` or `sed` to find out what programs are begin used.

Comment: Wow, no comments or upvotes in three days - I had given up hope.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user1717828 glad to help.